# std::complex and GCC's g++: ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field

Tags: c++, gcc, deserialization

I'm trying to write a C++ library, which is going to target an ARM Linux system, but leaving C-compatible "bindings" and structs for using with CFFI on other languages.

The library deals with a serial stream that I don't control, and that I want to de-serialize.

I have the following (simplified) struct on `stream.h`:

```c
#pragma once 

#include "cpp_compat.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BB_FRAME_IQ_SAMPLES_COUNT 512
#define BB_FRAME_MAGIC 0xAA5555AA

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
    {
        /** Every frame starts with BB_FRAME_MAGIC. */
        uint32_t magic;

        /** Baseband IQ samples. */
        fcomplex_t bb_iq_samples[BB_FRAME_IQ_SAMPLES_COUNT];

        uint8_t someparams[9]; // simplification

        uint32_t reserved_n[6];

        uint32_t crc;
    } bb_frame_t;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`fcomplex_t` is where the C/C++ compatibility happens, thanks to `cpp_compat.h`:

```c
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <complex>

using fcomplex_t = std::complex<float>;

#else
#include <complex.h>

typedef _Complex float fcomplex_t;

#endif
```

However, I'm having this warning when building the code in C++:

```
[build] stream.h:41:37: warning: ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field ‘fcomplex_t <unnamed struct>::bb_iq_samples [512]’
[build]    41 |         fcomplex_t bb_iq_samples[BB_FRAME_IQ_SAMPLES_COUNT];
[build]       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And this scares me because I really need the packed attribute to work to correctly de-serialize the frames from the serial stream.

The compiler is `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (GCC) 12.2.1 20221203 [releases/gcc-12 revision c03cb4b762aceeba95da918b042583af0d9f6030]`. I got it from a buildroot using the Linaro toolchain.

So the question is, how can I make this work without errors?

P.S.: It's worth noting that the C++ standard guarantees that `std::complex<float>` and `_Complex float` are memory-compatible.

EDIT 1: In the meanwhile, I found out that x86's GCC also complains about the issue but Clang (tested with version 16) does not. **Seems to be something GCC-specific.**

Comment: The array must be properly aligned regardless of the attribute, the compiler just says it using other words. Reorder the members to achieve the packed struct.

Comment: @273K: Testing rearranging the members to put `bb_iq_samples` shows it does not silence the compiler message, and it would not solve OP’s problem since they are using the structure to layout bytes in memory for serialization/deserialization, so the member order cannot be changed.

Comment: The compiler tells you what it does not like, the `fcomplex_t` type is non-POD. You can use `_Complex float` for it.

Comment: @Eric Using structures for direct serializing data in memory is always bad idea. Particularly, does someone guarantee that `std::complex<float>` and `_Complex` have the identical layouts?

Comment: @273K: The C++ standard specifies the memory layout for `complex<T>`, as the question states.

Comment: @273K There are very specific exceptions for `std::complex` in the C++ standard that effectively guarantee that the layout is compatible (with reasonable assumptions on structure of C++ implementations in general if they intent to support C as well).

Comment: @Eric You seem don't get that OP wants to use their library in C and C++. Thus, I ask, if someone guarantees that C++ `std::complex<float>` and C `_Complex` have the identical layouts.

Comment: @user You seem don't get that OP wants to use their library in C and C++. Thus, I ask, if someone guarantees that C++ `std::complex<float>` and C `_Complex` have the identical layouts.

Comment: @273K: As you have been told three times now, once in the question, once by me, and once by user17732522, the C++ standard guarantees the layout of `std::complex<float>`. Perhaps I failed to mention explicitly that that specified layout is, of course, the same as `_Complex float`, and both C and C++ guarantee it is equivalent to an array of two `float`, the first being the real part and the second being the imaginary part. These guarantees are made just so that the layout and behaviors desired by OP in this case will be provided.

Comment: @273K Yes, it does. C specifies the layout as two adjacent `float` and there are exceptions on the behavior of `reinterpret_cast` in the C++ standard that effectively also require implementation as two adjacent `float` (in the same order) without any padding or other members. So any reasonable implementation will have their memory layout compatible (although not _layout-compatible_ in the C++ sense).

Comment: Specifically, I want to write the library in C++ and add `extern "C"` functions to make it usable from C. Thus I want to make the headers compatible.

But even if I didn't want to make headers compatible, I still have an error about being impossible to pack using std::complex, so the C vs C++ compat discussion ends up being tangential.

Comment: PS: Basically, the whole `std::complex` vs `_Complex` thing was how I found the error, because I just had it with `_Complex float`, and it works without warnings that way.

Comment: Added some more information. Seems that Clang is just fine with the C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised the problem on GCC.

It's apparently an intended behaviour of the compiler.

More details in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108342